# problem of visibility with cmake-presets inheritance

Tags: cmake, cmake-presets

`cmake-presets` supports inheritance. That is nice, providing that the parent preset is visible, but not work otherwise. Taking for example with `preset1.json`:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "configurePresets": [
   {
    "name": "base_preset"
   }
}
```

`preset2.json`:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "configurePresets": [
   {
    "name": "child_preset",
    "inherits": [
        "base_preset"
     ]
   }
}
```

and `CMakePresets.json`:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "include": [
       "preset1.json",
       "preset2.json"
  ]
}
```

The inherited preset does not work because `base_preset` is unreachable. Is it a bug or intended behavior?

Comment: You forgot to include preset1.json in preset2.json.

Comment: @Corristo I don't think they forgot. I'm assuming that's the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's intended behavior.

You assume that the inclusion order in CMakePresets.json would also cover the declaration and inheritance order of presets, but instead each file needs to include it's inherited presets.

In your case `preset2.json` needs to include `preset1.json` to have  `base_preset` visible.

[Quoting Kyle Edwards (Jun '23) on "CMakePresets: Include Behavior"](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmakepreset-include-behavior/8379/7):

> When one preset points to another, either through inheritance or as a
> build/test/package preset associated with a configure preset, the file
> containing the build/test/package preset must include the file
> containing the configure preset.